# Can we invoke Visual studio's "Find All References" in C# code? How?

Tags: c#, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, envdte

I am trying to invoke visual studio's **Find All References** in a visual studio add-in project(vsix).
EnvDTE and EnvDTE80 assemblies have been used for build features or add files to project features.

Wandering, if there is any api to invoke **Find All References** feature as well.

**Please Note**: I have tried Roslyn compiler's FindAllReference method, but did not help as it was not showing line number.

Comment: Did you want to get a function to obtain all the references' info in vsix project?

Comment: VS does not have this menu. Does `Object Browser` window you want? Did you want to get the usage of all the project reference?

Comment: Yes you are right @PerryQian-MSFT , Then can I invoke find Find all Reference menu item

Comment: Actually, you can call [IFindAllReferencesService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.findallreferences.ifindallreferencesservice?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) Interface to get the find all reference window. Also, I suggest you could get `Object Browser tool menu` by [IDM_VS_TOOL_OBJBROWSER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/guids-and-ids-of-visual-studio-toolbars?view=vs-2017#tool-window-toolbars). And Find All Reference menu item does not list on the official document.

Comment: Thank you so much @PerryQian-MSFT. I will try this out and update status here. Thanks :)

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Hi Perry, It will be great help if you can share some document or example of IFindAllReferencesService. Thanks in advance.